# Using multiple EqReasoning instantiations conveniently

Tags: agda, reasoning

Is there a way to conveniently use multiple instantiations of `EqReasoning` where the underlying `Setoid` is not necessarily semantic equality (i.e. `≡-Reasoning` cannot be used)? The reason that `≡-Reasoning` is convenient is that the type argument is implicit and it uniquely determines the `Setoid` in use by automatically selecting semantic equality. When using arbitrary `Setoid`s there is no such unique selection. However a number of structures provide a canonical way to lift a `Setoid`:

- `Data.Maybe` and `Data.Covec` have a `setoid` member.
- `Data.Vec.Equality.Equality` provides enough definitions to write a canonical `Setoid` lifting for `Vec` as well. Interestingly there is also is a slightly different equality available at `Relation.Binary.Vec.Pointwise`, but it does not provide a direct lifting either albeit implementing all the necessary bits.
- `Data.List` ships a `Setoid` lifting in `Relation.Binary.List.Pointwise`.
- `Data.Container` also knows how to lift a `Setoid`.

By using any of these structures, one automatically gets to work with multiple `Setoid`s even if one started out with one. When proofs use these structures (multiple of them in a single proof), it becomes difficult to write down the proof, because `EqReasoning` must be instantiated for all of them even though each particular `Setoid` is kind of obvious. This can be done by renaming `begin_`, `_≈⟨_⟩_` and `_∎`, but I don't consider this renaming convenient.

Consider for example, a proof in the `Setoid` of `Maybe` where a sequence of arguments needs to be wrapped in `Data.Maybe.Eq.just` (think `cong just`) or a proof in an arbitrary `Setoid` that temporarily needs to wrap things in a `just` constructor exploiting its injectivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the only way Agda can pick something for you is when it is uniquely determined by the context. In the case of `EqReasoning`, there isn't usually enough information to pin down the `Setoid`, even worse actually: you could have two different `Setoid`s over the same `Carrier` and `_≈_` (consider for example two definitionally unequal proofs of `trans`itivity in the `isEquivalence` field).

---

However, Agda does allow special form of implicit arguments, which can be filled as long as there is only one value of the desired type. These are known as *instance* arguments (think instance as in Haskell type class instances).

To demonstrate roughly how this works:

```
postulate
  A : Set
  a : A
```

Now, instance arguments are wrapped in double curly braces `{{}}`:

```
elem : {{x : A}} → A
elem {{x}} = x
```

If we decide to later use `elem` somewhere, Agda will check for any values of type `A` in scope and if there's only one of them, it'll fill that one in for `{{x : A}}`. If we added:

```
postulate
  b : A
```

Agda will now complain that:

```
Resolve instance argument _x_7 : A. Candidates: [a : A, b : A]
```

---

Because Agda already allows you to perform computations on type level, instance arguments are deliberately limited in what they can do, namely Agda won't perform recursive search to fill them in. Consider for example:

```
eq : ... → IsEquivalence _≈_ → IsEquivalence (Eq _≈_)
```

where `Eq` is `Data.Maybe.Eq` mentioned in your question. When you then require Agda to fill in an instance argument of a type `IsEquivalence (Eq _≈_)`, it won't try to find something of type `IsEquivalence _≈_` and apply `eq` to it.

---

With that out of the way, let's take a look at what could work. However, bear in mind that all this stands on unification and as such you might need to push it in the right direction here and there (and if the types you are dealing with become complex, unification might require you to give it so many directions that it won't be worth it in the end).

Personally, I find instance arguments a bit fragile and I usually avoid them (and from a quick check, it would seem that so does the standard library), but your experience might vary.

Anyways, here we go. I constructed a (totally nonsensical) example to demonstrate how to do it. Some boilerplate first:

```
open import Data.Maybe
open import Data.Nat
open import Relation.Binary

import Relation.Binary.EqReasoning as EqR
```

To make this example self-contained, I wrote some kind of `Setoid` with natural numbers as its carrier:

```
data _≡ℕ_ : ℕ → ℕ → Set where
  z≡z :                    0     ≡ℕ 0
  s≡s : ∀ {m n} → m ≡ℕ n → suc m ≡ℕ suc n

ℕ-setoid : Setoid _ _
ℕ-setoid = record
  { _≈_     = _≡ℕ_
  ; isEquivalence = record
    { refl  = refl
    ; sym   = sym
    ; trans = trans
    }
  }
  where
  refl : Reflexive _≡ℕ_
  refl {zero}  = z≡z
  refl {suc _} = s≡s refl

  sym : Symmetric _≡ℕ_
  sym z≡z     = z≡z
  sym (s≡s p) = s≡s (sym p)

  trans : Transitive _≡ℕ_
  trans z≡z          q  = q
  trans (s≡s p) (s≡s q) = s≡s (trans p q)
```

Now, the `EqReasoning` module is parametrized over a `Setoid`, so usually you do something like this:

```
open EqR ℕ-setoid
```

However, we'd like to have the `Setoid` parameter to be implicit (instance) rather than explicit, so we define and open a dummy module:

```
open module Dummy {c ℓ} {{s : Setoid c ℓ}} = EqR s
```

And we can write this simple proof:

```
idʳ : ∀ n → n ≡ℕ (n + 0)
idʳ 0 = z≡z
idʳ (suc n) = begin
  suc n        ≈⟨ s≡s (idʳ n) ⟩
  suc (n + 0)  ∎
```

Notice that we never had to specify `ℕ-setoid`, the instance argument picked it up because it was the only type-correct value.

Now, let's spice it up a bit. We'll add `Data.Maybe.setoid` into the mix. Again, because instance arguments do *not* perform a recursive search, we'll have to define the setoid ourselves:

```
Maybeℕ-setoid = setoid ℕ-setoid
_≡M_ = Setoid._≈_ Maybeℕ-setoid
```

I'm going to postulate few stupid things just to demonstrate that Agda indeed picks correct setoids:

```
postulate
  comm : ∀ m n → (m + n) ≡ℕ (n + m)
  eq0  : ∀ n → n ≡ℕ 0
  eq∅  : just 0 ≡M nothing

lem : ∀ n → just (n + 0) ≡M nothing
lem n = begin
  just (n + 0)  ≈⟨ just
    (begin
      n + 0  ≈⟨ comm n 0 ⟩
      n      ≈⟨ eq0 n ⟩
      0      ∎
    )⟩
  just 0        ≈⟨ eq∅ ⟩
  nothing       ∎
```

Comment: This is an awesome way to solve the task at had. Still I trust your concern about instance arguments and will keep using the renaming technique if it doesn't get out of hand. If you happen to know another alternative (even a workaround that slightly bends the problem statement), I'd be happy to upvote another answer.

Comment: @Helmut: I mean, by all means try this out and see if it's fine for your use case. It's just that I (usually) prefer to be more precise at the cost of being slighly more verbose. But I like your alternative solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured an alternative to the proposed solution using instance arguments that slightly bends the requirements, but fits my purpose. The major burden in the question was having to explicitly open `EqReasoning` multiple times and especially having to invent new names for the contained symbols. A slight improvement would be to pass the correct `Setoid` once per relation proof. In other words passing it to `begin_` or `_∎` somehow. Then we could make the `Setoid` implicit for all the other functions!

```
import Relation.Binary.EqReasoning as EqR
import Relation.Binary using (Setoid)
module ExplicitEqR where
 infix 1 begin⟨_⟩_
 infixr 2 _≈⟨_⟩_ _≡⟨_⟩_
 infix 2 _∎
 begin⟨_⟩_ : ∀ {c l} (X : Setoid c l) → {x y : Setoid.Carrier X} → EqR._IsRelatedTo_ X x y → Setoid._≈_ X x y
 begin⟨_⟩_ X p = EqR.begin_ X p
 _∎ : ∀ {c l} {X : Setoid c l} → (x : Setoid.Carrier X) → EqR._IsRelatedTo_ X x x
 _∎ {X = X} = EqR._∎ X
 _≈⟨_⟩_ : ∀ {c l} {X : Setoid c l} → (x : Setoid.Carrier X) → {y z : Setoid.Carrier X} → Setoid._≈_ X x y → EqR._IsRelatedTo_ X y z → EqR._IsRelatedTo_ X x z
 _≈⟨_⟩_ {X = X} = EqR._≈⟨_⟩_ X
 _≡⟨_⟩_ : ∀ {c l} {X : Setoid c l} → (x : Setoid.Carrier X) → {y z : Setoid.Carrier X} → x ≡ y → EqR._IsRelatedTo_ X y z → EqR._IsRelatedTo_ X x z
 _≡⟨_⟩_ {X = X} = EqR._≡⟨_⟩_ X
```

Reusing the nice example from Vitus answer, we can write it:

```
lem : ∀ n → just (n + 0) ≡M nothing
lem n = begin⟨ Data.Maybe.setoid ℕ-setoid ⟩
  just (n + 0)  ≈⟨ just
    (begin⟨ ℕ-setoid ⟩
      n + 0  ≈⟨ comm n 0 ⟩
      n      ≈⟨ eq0 n ⟩
      0      ∎
    )⟩
  just 0        ≈⟨ eq∅ ⟩
  nothing       ∎
  where open ExplicitEqR
```

One still has to mention the `Setoid`s in use, to avoid the use of instance arguments as presented by Vitus. However the technique makes it significantly more convenient.

Comment: This way of reasoning will be available in the next version of the standard library as `Relation.Binary.SetoidReasoning`.